# Как вызвать сам php код?

Tags: php

Вот есть у меня код

```
<php
    $filename = 'pesnike.txt';
    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+')) {
    echo "Не могу открыть файл '$filename'";
    exit;
    }
    %content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

    $content = str_replace('{user_name}', 'Иван Петрович', $content);
    if(fwrite($handle, $content) === FALSE)  {
        echo "Не могу сохранить в файл '$filename'";
        exit;
    }
fclose($handle);
?>
```

А как мне его вызвать, если он просто будет записан, толку от него не будет?

Answer (score 1):

Сохранить в файл, вызвать файл. Либо командой php filename, либо из браузера. Вообще я, если честно, немного в шоке.

И в 7 строке %content на $content замените

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам статья для начала, [познать азы PHP](http://www.phpfaq.ru/na_tanke)

Посоветую 2 варианта:

**1) Вариант — установка денвера.** 
Это самый простой вариант, при условии что у вас OS семейства Windows.
На сайте [denwer.ru](http://denwer.ru) вы найдет подробную инструкцию об установе и настройке пакета.

**2) Вариант — установка LAMP сервера.**
Этот вариант сложнее, и но научит вас принципам работы в Linux системе в часности настройке сервера на Linux Ubuntu.

Приступим:

1. Необходимо скачать образ дистрибутива с сайта разработчика [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/server/overview)
2. Установить его, куда удобно. Можно на виртуальную машину можно сразу на свой компьютер. Но для начала советую установить на виртуальную машину. Устанавливайте все по умолчанию, если правильно все сделали у вас появиться после перезагрузки срока входа в систему, вводите свой логин и пароль.
3. Приступим к установе программного обеспечения.

Установка apache2 + phph5 + mysql + phpmyadmin одной строкой

```
 aptitude install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient15-dev apache2 apache2-doc apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils libexpat1 ssl-cert libapache2-mod-php5 libapache2-mod-ruby php5 php5-common php5-curl php5-dev php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-mhash php5-ming php5-mysql php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl phpmyadmin
```

Это установит и настроит ваш LAMP сервер.

Вообще вам поможет статья по настройке от [сюда](http://rubuntu.ru/blog/server/435/nastrojka-apache-2-nginx-php-5-mysql-memcached-eaccelerator-sphinx-v-ubuntu.html), сам пользовался неоднократно!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала исправьте:

```
<php
```

на:

```
<?php
```

А то вместо выполнения скрипта выведется листинг кода :))

Answer (score 0):

Вам лучше с начала изучить основные принципы работы php, а не сразу кидаться в работу с файлами. Чтобы узнать и понять как вызывать php скрипт установите web- сервер с поддержкой php. И первый раз лучше всё устанавливать самому, а не использовать готовые пакеты вроде xampp.