# Не работает PHP в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

Установил php на apache server на ос Ubuntu  16.04.
При команде `php -v` Выводит:

`PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.15 (cli) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.15, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies`

Создаю файл info.php в нем ставлю код:

`<?php  phpinfo(); ?>`

и захожу на URL 127.0.0.1/info.php и начинается скачивания файла info.php
что мне делать ?

Comment: Для начала, советовал бы перейти на [Nginx & php-fpm](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04-ru). Как устанавливали php?

Comment: А вы настроили apache на использование этого самого php?

Comment: @andreymal а как это делать ?

Comment: Инструкций в гугле навалом, не?

Comment: другие дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767041/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/34420/178576), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18642/178576)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Связать установленный apache и php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/346052/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-apache-%d0%b8-php)